# C# Is there a good way to store multiple objects and still be easy to access

Tags: c#, arrays, class, multidimensional-array

Maybe it is hard to understand but I want to know if there is a way to store multiple variables like a 2d Array but use commands to access it easily?

Example:

```
ItemID = "1";ItemName = "Apple";ItemPrice = 10; ItemLocation = "Storage";
ItemID = "2";ItemName = "Bread";ItemPrice = 20; ItemLocation = "Outside";
ItemID = "3";ItemName = "TV";ItemPrice = 30; ItemLocation = "House";
```

So I can access it with a command like `Item.Name(1);` to get the name of it and `Item.ID("Apple");` to get the ID of it (names and IDs are unique). So later, I can request everything when I get the ID or the Name of the item.

Something like this:

```
int IID = Item.ID("Bread");
string IName = Item.Name(2);
int IPrice = Item.Price(IID);
string ILocation = Item.Location(IID);
//So .ID return the ID but requires string Name
//And everything else requires the ID
```

Thanks in advance

-Coffee

Sry for my bad grammar still learning :x

Comment: As I understand this you are between a Datarow or Tuple object!?

Comment: Yeah i think a tuple is what i was looking for. Is there a way to rename the items, so its not Item1,Item2, Item3.....

Comment: Is `Item` supposed to be a helper class for your list of items?  It's not clear what `Item` is, based on the name I would assume it's a specific item in the list.  Not the List itself...

Comment: Sry Item was just a name i choose for the Command for an example what i want it to look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom list:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

...

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemLocation { get; set; }
}

public class ItemList : List<Item>
{
    public Item GetByName(string name)
    {
        return this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemName == name);
    }

    public Item GetById(int id)
    {
        return this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId== id);        
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var itemList = new ItemList();
itemList.Add(new Item { ItemId = 1, ItemName = "Some Item", ItemLocation = "Wherever" });
itemList.Add(new Item { ItemId = 2, ItemName = "Some Other Item", ItemLocation = "" });

var item = itemList.GetByName("Some Item");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question fully, but taking a jab here

There is many ways to skin this cats and here are some thoughts:

- You can write a class, struct, a Tuple to model the Item type
- You can have a dictionary using the ID as the key and store the item object as the value. This will allow easy and fast lookup by ID but less to search by name OR
- Store the item list in standard collection like a List and use linq query to filter and find the item OR
- Write your own Collection class that perhaps derive from List and then you can write custom methods such as ID(), Name() OR
- Write extension methods ID(), Name(), etc. on the collection types you use like this

```
public static Item ID(this IList<Item> items, string name) 
{   
  return items.SingleOrDefault(e=>e.Name == name); 
}
```